# RichFaces Slider not working on iOS device

Tags: slider, richfaces

we are using RichFaces 3.3 in an application and rich:inputNumberSlider. There is no real support for iOS devices yet. I can click the pointer, but I am not able to slide on iPad.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about Richfaces 3.3 + iOS compatibility, but based on the Richfaces 4.3 showcase notes, it should work for you on iOS. See: https://github.com/richfaces/showcase

Readme says:

> This showcase is also mobile compatible with WebKit based browsers; this includes iOS, Android, and Others.

However I'm not sure if it's an option for you to upgrade. 
Moreover I'm not sure if I remember correctly, but I believe you can use the same components for mobile as you do for the non-mobile ones (there are however some rules for content creation I think).

**EDIT**:

Well I think I have sad news for you. It sounds, like you're not the first one facing the issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10918

Unless it's solved upstream I don't think you can move on. However you could try to put some heat on the bug (adding your environment as a comment, and possibly vote for it, probably ask for the workaround there) or, you could try to check the Richfaces source code and provide the fix/patch yourself.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the showcase with my iPad, I see the same behaviour like RF 3.x. It is possible to click but not possible to slide.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UISlider`.

First set `IBOutlet` devices:

`.h` file:

```
IBOutlet UISlider *Slider1;
```

`.m` file:

```
lbl3.text=@"slider string";
[Slider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
Slider1.value=0.0;

// Slider control
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider{

    lbl3.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(int)((slider.value)*100) ] ;     
    NSLog(@"%@",lbl3.text);

}
```